# Stopping negative results from being set

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script where users can send each other in-game money.

The problem is, users are typing in “give -99999 money to *username*” and then my script takes the 99999 from the user they type in and gives it to them.

So here is my script:

```
if(isset($_POST['usernameofmoney'])) 
{
    $resson= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usernameofmoney']);
    $resson2 = strip_tags($resson);

    $bannedusername= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['money']);
    $bannedusername2 = strip_tags($bannedusername);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $values = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    // We do this if they do no have enough coins
    if ( $values['money'] < $bannedusername2  ) {
        echo  "You Don't Have Enough Money Sorry";
        die;
    }

    if ( $values['money'] > $bannedusername2 ) {
        // Take the coins from the 1 users
        $gfgdgdfgds = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money = money - ".$bannedusername2."
        WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'") or die(mysql_error()); 
        // Add the coins to the new user
        $gfgdgdfgdsf = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money = money + ".$bannedusername2."
        WHERE username = '".$resson2."'") or die(mysql_error()); 

        echo "The Money Have Been Sent.";
    }
}
```

I know that I should be using PDO, and I will be switching over to PDO tonight.

Here is were i do the check to see if the user has the money to send.

```
 if ( $values['money'] < $bannedusername2  ) {
        echo  "You Don't Have Enough Money Sorry";
        die;
    }
```

$values['money'] is there money and $bannedusername2  is the money they want to give which they have typed in.  So if there money is less than the money they type in then it will stop the script but they are typing in -99999 and its letting them though..

Comment: How to check if something is negative: `if($something < 0)`

Comment: I particularly like the way you name variables, so meaningful and easy to mantain

Comment: i do that but the script still lets them though

Comment: You're not checking the value of `$bannedusername2`. Your users can put any value they like there. And why call something that has a monetary value "$bannedusername2"?

Comment: @BillyWhite: Can you show how you did that in your question, please?

Comment: Also, why is there a `strip_tags` in there?

Comment: I have edited my question to show how i check also i do strip_tags to strip java script and anything nasty.

Comment: @BillyWhite I don't see this addition you're talking about. A couple things: 1) it's "javascript", not "java script"; it has nothing to do with Java; 2)strip_tags() isn't enough to protect against XSS, if that's what you wanted. Oh, and use PDO now, I doubt you will be changing everything after you struggled so much to make it work the way it is now; make changes before it gets too painful to change

Comment: @DamienPirsy: How is `strip_tags` not enough to prevent XSS? (It’s a *bad* way, but not insecure AFAIK when used with no arguments.)

Comment: you should use script_tags when you output content to the browser, javascript code won't have any effect on server, also you don't need a second variable when you run a function to change one, you can just do `$resson = strip_tags($resson);`, finally what you need to do is check if `$_POST['money'] < 0` before doing anything in your function, also please use descriptive variable names

Comment: @minitech You should at least couple it with htmlspecialchars()

Comment: @DamienPirsy: Why *couple*? One or the other would do, no?

Comment: koala_dev  thank you ill do that now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is maybe not exactly the answer to your question but...

... if I understand well, your logic here is to:

1. Check if there is enough money to send by issuing a `SELECT` request,
2. *if so*, do the monetary exchange by doing two successive `UPDATE` queries.

This probably works well while you are alone testing the application. However, remember that on production there will be several *concurrent* access to your DB.

So, if say User A, having $150, give $100 to both User C and User D at the same time the following scenario is possible:

1. Check if User A has more that $100. Yes.
2. Check if User A has more than $100. Yes.
3. Since (1) is true, give $100 to User B.
4. Since (2) is true, give $100 to User B.

Oups.

---

An other kind of possible failure is a success of the first `UPDATE`, but a failure of the second (for whatever reason). In that case, one user will have is account decreased. And the money just have vanished...

Oups again.

---

To prevent those pitfalls you have to ensure at least:

- That you use [transactional tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engine-compare-transactions.html) (i.e.: *InnoDB*),
- that you run at [repeatable read](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-transaction.html#isolevel_repeatable-read) isolation level (the default for *InnoDB*),
- and that you wrap [atomic DB access](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) in a [transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) (`BEGIN TRANSACTION` .... `COMMIT`)

In addition, instead of a `SELECT`+`UPDATE`, I would rewrite your first `UPDATE` request as:

```
UPDATE users SET money = money - amount WHERE username = "User A"
AND money >= amount;
```

And then I would check if the `UPDATE` has affected 0 ou 1 row. The former meaning "not enough money".